# TypeError: ManyRelatedManager object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I am not able to resolve the error named Many Related Manager is not iterable. I have Models named A and B as shown below:

```
class B(models.Model):
     indicator = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
     tags = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)


class A(models.Model):
     definitions = models.ManyToManyField(B)
     user = models.ForeignKey('userauth.ABCUSER', null=True, blank=True)
     project = models.ForeignKey('userauth.ProjectList', null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to retrieve definitions attribute of Model A which includes attributes of Class B. I have tried to retrieve it as shown below, But It gives me an error:

> TypeError: ManyRelatedManager object is not iterable

```
 if tbl_scope == 'Generic':
        checked_objects = A.objects.get(user=user, project=project)


 for checked_object in checked_objects.definitions:
        print(checked_object.indicator)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

An m2m field is returned as a related manager object so its not iterable. You need to use all to convert it to a queryset to make it iterable.

```
if tbl_scope == 'Generic':
        checked_objects = A.objects.get(user=user, project=project)


 for checked_object in checked_objects.definitions.all():
        print(checked_object.indicator)
```

You can read more about [m2m](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field.